# How do I stop EF Core from Auto creating Property even though manually configured?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following classes and configuration

```
    public class ApplicationRole
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<ApplicationPermission> Permissions { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationPermission
    {
        public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
    }

//Configuration for ApplicationPermission

            builder.HasOne<ApplicationRole>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(r=>r.RoleId);
```

After running the migrations in my ApplicationPermission table I get 2 filelds RoleId as expected, but also ApplicationRoleId which is automatically created by EF.

So how do I just keep my RoleId in the table and disable EF from creating the other field.

I read that you might need to disable EF conventions. Is that correct and the only way?

Comment: `.WithMany()` is empty, so EF sees `ApplicationRole.Permissions` as another association.

Comment: @GertArnold So WithMany should be WithMany<ApplictionRole>()?

Comment: No, it should be something like `WithMany(r => r.Permissions)`. Worth reading [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) documentation topics.

Comment: Great got it. Appreicated.